# .End(xlDown).Row changes from Excel 2007 to 2010

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

After updating from Office 2007 to Office 2010, the macros that worked perfectly in Excel 2007 but do not work in 2010. Specifically i recieved a error on this line:

```
    y = Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
```

Ther error is "error 6  Overflow". I have come to realize that it is due to Excel selecting the max number(1048576) of rows in excel that creates the overflow. There is only data in 975 of these rows. In 2007 it only selected the rows with data. **I am wondering what has caused the change in the way that code is handled from 2007 to 2010?** Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: If you have values in column A below row 2, the code should work the same in either version of Excel. If there is nothing below cell A2, then `y` will equal the last row in the sheet and cause the overflow error if `y` is an `int`. Can you post some more code for context? What is in column A?

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that `y variable` (and other variables referring to row numbers) are declared as `Long`, like:

```
Dim y As Long
```

I could guess that your variables are `Integer` at the moment.

I could guess that you have possibly migrated your file from `.xls` into `.xlsm` in the meantime which could cause some of that problems.

Comment: I know that this would stop the overflow but i am more interested in why it is selecting every row possible in excel when only 975 have data. i am more interested in why it is doing this.

Comment: to answer this question I would need to see the whole code, file and know file and code evolution :)

Comment: In this case, both **Santosh** and **KazJaw** are right and both answers should be incorporated by OP.

Comment: The file originally is a .xls and i am resaving as .xlsm; if i just copied to a new file and thated the new as a .xlsm would it elminiate the complications between migrating the file?

Comment: we still don't see the way you declare your `y variable`. If you additionally keep my advice (from answer above) you will succeed :)

Comment: Seeing [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16822875/vba-meaning-of-ampersand-in-range) I'm sure you need to change into `Dim y as Long` as suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
  With Worksheets("Raw Data")
        y = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
```

Comment: @woody If the records are more than 32,767 you need to declare `y variable` as long as answered by kazJaw.