# VBA meaning of ampersand in range

Tags: vba, excel

Im clueless on what the meaning of `Range("B1:U" & y)` is where y is

```
Dim y As Integer
y = Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
```

What is the ampersand y doing here?

Comment: Add a message box `Msgbox "B1:U" & y` . It creates a string which your range needs. It concatenates the integer value ( row number) to the string.

Comment: it's rather continuation of the other [question of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16799275/endxldown-row-changes-from-excel-2007-to-2010), I think...

Comment: What do you eman by it creates a string? why does the range need a string?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The ampersand is the Concatenation operator in the Visual Basic based languages, like VBA, in your case you are taking the string "B1:U" and concatenating the value of the variable y to the end of the string. Since y is defined as an Integer, VBA will first convert the value of y to a string and then perform the concatenation. For Example, if the value of y is 15, since that is the last cell in the range "A2" on the worksheet "Raw Data" then the concatenation of "B1:U" & y would be "B1:U15"